# none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied kotlin error

Tags: kotlin

I was trying some basics of kotlin ->

program :

```
fun createDate(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int, hour: Int = 0, minute: Int = 0, second: Int = 0) {
print("TEST", "$day-$month-$year $hour:$minute:$second")
}
createDate(1,7,1997)
```

error :

```
error: none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Any?): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Boolean): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Byte): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: CharArray): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Double): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Float): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Int): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Long): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun print(message: Short): Unit defined in kotlin.io
print("TEST", "$day-$month-$year $hour:$minute:$second")
```

any idea what I am doing wrong, I was following this -> https://www.toptal.com/software/kotlin-android-language

Comment: `print` only accepts a single argument, you're passing it two.

Comment: The message is relatively clear... there exist only methods that have 1 parameter, but you pass 2 (first. "TEST", second: "$day-...$second"). You may wanted to use something like: "TEST $day-...$second" instead. Note that I do not know which `print`-function the author of that article used... probably it's a self-built one...

Comment: Oh dear... that article is already more than 2 years old and uses Kotlin version 1.0.1... you may want to use a tutorial that was written more recently or if you like the style just take it with a grain of salt...

Answer (score 4):

It should be like this,because kotlin default print funtion  have only one parameters

```
fun createDate(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int, hour: Int = 0, minute: Int = 0, second: Int = 0) {
    print("$day-$month-$year $hour:$minute:$second")
}
```

Because kotlin default print function like this

```
/** Prints the given message and newline to the standard output stream. */
public expect fun println(message: Any?)

 /** Prints the given message to the standard output stream. */
public expect fun print(message: Any?)
```

so you cant send double parameters in print function.so  use

```
print("$day-$month-$year $hour:$minute:$second")
```

instead of

```
print("TEST", "$day-$month-$year $hour:$minute:$second")
```

Comment: the main problem turned out to be the no of parameters in the print function. thnx

Answer (score 0):

> Error on line

```
createDate(1,7,1997)
```

because you call the createDate() function but **arguments** is **mismatched**.

Let us overwrite this function:

```
createDate(1,7,1997,5,24,15)
```